# Kotlin - android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using `org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions` to parcel data.

This is my data class

```
@Parcelize
data class MusicTrack(
    val id: Long,
    val title: String,
    val albumId: String,
    val artist: String,
    val duration: String,
    val trackArt: String = "",
    val fileUri: Uri) : Parcelable
```

This is how I send my data across

```
  override fun playTrack(position: Int, musicList: ArrayList<MusicTrack>) {
    info { musicList }
    val bundle = bundleOf(
            Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACKS to musicList,
            Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACK_POSITION to position)


    MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(this).transportControls.playFromUri(Uri.parse("Hack"), bundle)
}
```

Then consuming the parcel like

```
  override fun onPlayFromUri(uri: Uri?, extras: Bundle?) {
        super.onPlayFromUri(uri, extras)

        val tracks = extras?.getParcelable<MusicTrack>(Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACKS) as ArrayList<*>

        info { tracks }

    }
```

Which throws the above error `android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:`

But, when I try to consume it in an activity with

```
    val songsList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("Extras")
    info { songsList }
```

It works! Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to read a single `MusicTrack`, but you have a list of them in a `Bundle`.
You need to call `getParcelableArrayList<MusicTrack>`.

Comment: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.wizmusicplayer.MusicTrack

Comment: extras?.getParcelableArrayList<MusicTrack>(Config.MusicConfig.MUSIC_TRACKS)

Comment: Looks like you're passing a Bundle to another process. Ensure this process has access to `MusicTrack` class and you're passing your classLoader while reading from Parcel.

Comment: Yes got it, had to set the classLoader

Comment: extras?.classLoader = this@MusicService.classLoader before accessing the paracelable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997550/unmarshalling-errors-in-android-app-with-custom-parcelable-classes/14093745#14093745

Answer (score -1):

Try this in **Buid.gradle** this solved my issue

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

Comment: I've added that to my gradle file